# Dot Product of Tensor row matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, tensor

I have a tensor that I need to dot product all its the row matrices in a vectorized way:
`a = np.zeros((3,4,2,2))+1`
which is a `3x4` tensor and elements are matrices 2x2. I need to dot product the 2x2 matrices in each row.
the result should be a `3x1` matrix that contains a `2x2` matrix filled with `8`s
I tried

```
a = np.zeros((3,4,2,2))+1
np.prod(a, axis= 1)
```

but it only gives the element-wise product:

```
array([[[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```

I need a vectorized function, not a for-loop.
I'd appreciate it if someone has a solution using NumPy or Scipy as TensorFlow is a huge dependency to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
def np_multi_matmul(tensor: np.ndarray, axis: int) -> np.ndarray:
    arrays = np.split(tensor, tensor.shape[axis], axis = axis)
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: np.matmul(y, x), arrays)
```

edit: first, split the array along the axis you want to reduce. then compute the matmul of each two matrices at a time. matmul will ignore all but the last two dimensions and compute their matrix multiplication result as long as the other dimensions of the array are the same.

Comment: sorry for the useless code. thanks for the edit